# Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime' from

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I m getting the error " Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime' from ...". I have tried every solution on the internet but nothing really works.
How can i solve it ?
Any suggestion would be greatly appriciated.

babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-react",
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        ["transform-runtime", {
            "helpers": false, // defaults to true
            "polyfill": false, // defaults to true
            "regenerator": true, // defaults to true
            "moduleName": "babel-runtime" // defaults to "babel-runtime"
        }]
    ]}
```

webpack

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css'],
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'),
        }
    },

    plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/index.html'
    })],
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    externals: {
        // global app config object
        config: JSON.stringify({
            apiUrl: 'https://obidentity-develop.azurewebsites.net/connect/token'
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you installed it?, ie- `npm install @babel/plugin-transform-runtime` ?

Comment: yes i have tried

Comment: Is it listed in your `package.json` file?

Comment: Oh, I see a problem, in your .babelrc, it should be, `"plugins": [["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",..`  , not just `"transform-runtime"`.

Comment: i just tried it. Same result...

Comment: "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.8.3",  "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4", "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",  "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0"

Comment: You have All of those installed?  You want only one.

Comment: This would be impossible to debug for you. Would need to evaluate the specific errors and other factors.  Just read the errors closely and debug from there. good luck!  Or maybe someone else will have some insight.

Comment: Does it work if you change your `@` alias to `@/`?

Comment: I was getting the same error in Create-React-App (CRA) when overriding the build config without ejecting. Installing the plugin with `yarn add -D @babel/plugin-transform-runtime` fixed it.

Comment: add everything under dependencies: {} instead of devDependencies: {}. This fixed issue for me. Also, answer below is correct as well. and do npm i -g jest as well.

Answer (score 15):

try to add

`"plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]`

in .babelrc

Answer (score 3):

I met this problem when I was running 2 different versions of node:

- terminal 1: node 14, `npm install`
- terminal 2: node 16, `npm run dev`

so the dependencies are mess up, and something very strange happens.

solution:

1. remove `node_modules` folder
2. open 1 terminal, `npm install` and `npm run dev`

Answer (score 0):

I deleted `".babelrc"`.

Then I use: `npm run dev`.

That fix the problem.